# Drop Shadow on text in textblock

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp

I have developed an app in which I used the textblock. Now I want to drop the shadow on the text like the given image

[image]

I used blur effect but it gives error.

```
private async void ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    br = new Border();
    Word_art obvwa = new Word_art();
    if (txtbox.Text == "")
    {
        var line = new MessageDialog("PLease enter the text");
        await line.ShowAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        TB1 = new TextBlock();
        TB1.FontSize = txtbox.FontSize;
        TB1.Foreground = txtbox.Foreground;

        SolidColorBrush sb = new SolidColorBrush();
        var color = sb.Color;

        TB1.Opacity = 60;                
        TB1.Text = txtbox.Text;
        var blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
        blur.BlurAmount = 5.0f;
        blur.Source = TB1.Text; 
        var sitem = stylecombo.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        string sitemfm = Convert.ToString(sitem.Content);
        FontFamily fm = new FontFamily(""+ sitemfm);
        TB1.FontFamily = fm;
```

I tried Microsoft.graphics.effect assembly but it's not included in my project.

Comment: What error does it give, what does your code look like, what have you tried?

Comment: var blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
        blur.BlurAmount = 5.0f;
        blur.Source = bitmap;

Comment: it gives missing library or assembly refference

Comment: which one gives you the error?

Comment: Did you include the proper assembly reference?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried/done. From my basic understanding you are using a library called Win2d (or should be), if you get a missing library/assembly reference error there is something wrong with the way you are including it. It also looks like win2d only works on Windows 8.1 or higher (which I do not have, so I can be of little help to you). I'd check this post out: https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/QuickStart.htm

Answer (score 4):

For creating `textblock` with shadow like above, you can just use the [WindowsUIDevLabs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs) library which wrapper the shadow controls. You can just configure the `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` properties for the shadow and it will take effects. Code like follows:

```
<Page
...
xmlns:common="using:SamplesCommon" >

   <common:CompositionShadow
       x:Name="shadowcontrol"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       BlurRadius="5"
       OffsetX="-1"
       OffsetY="-1"
       ShadowOpacity=".7"
       Color="Green">      
       <TextBlock
           Foreground="#6B0F02"
           FontSize="48"
           TextWrapping="Wrap">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       </TextBlock>         
   </common:CompositionShadow>
```

And the result:

[image]

And for how to use the `WindowsUIDevLabs`, please download the package and add the [SamplesCommon](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SamplesCommon) project to your solution, add reference to your project. You can also directly running the sample inside the package for further testing.